# Positioning select element in HTML

Tags: html, css, forms

I have this select element on my HTML which looks like this

[image]

Now I want to position my select element on the top left of the division border and It won't seem to move. Am I doing it wrong? Do I have to add something my codes?

Here's the css:

```css
<style>

 body {
    background-image: url("img/wood.jpg");
 }
 
 ​.MySelectCPU{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:200px;
    }​​​
 
</style>
```

Here's the html code:

```html
<div style="font-family: Questrial; font-size:40px;">Administrative Control Panel Page</div><br>


 <div style="width:500px; font-family: Questrial; font-size:20px; border:1px solid #000; padding:100px;" align="center">
 
 <select id="MySelectCPU" onchange="location = this.value;">
  <option disabled selected hidden>Deployed Equipments</option>
  <option value="viewcpu.php">Deployed CPUs</option>
  <option value="viewmouse.php">Deployed Mouse</option>
  <option value="viewkeyboard.php">Deployed Keyboards</option>
  <option value="viewmonitor.php">Deployed Monitors</option>
  <option value="viewlaptop.php">Deployed Laptops</option>
 </select>

 </div><br clear="all">
 
 <span style="padding-right: 10px; font-family: Questrial;" ><a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</font></a></span>
 <span style="font-family: Questrial;"><a href="home.php" class="btn btn-primary">Profile</font></a></span>
```

Comment: You're declaring 100px padding inside your div on this line `<div style="width:500px; font-family: Questrial; font-size:20px; border:1px solid #000; padding:100px;" align="center">`. As a result its knocking out past your defined width and forcing the element to the center, and if I'm understanding your question correctly you want it in the top left?

Comment: It just makes the border narrower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `padding`, use `height` and `width`.

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  font-family: Questrial;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  /* padding: 100px; */
}
```

```html
<div style="font-family: Questrial; font-size:40px;">Administrative Control Panel Page</div><br>

<div id="container">

  <select id="MySelectCPU" onchange="location = this.value;">
  <option disabled selected hidden>Deployed Equipments</option>
  <option value="viewcpu.php">Deployed CPUs</option>
  <option value="viewmouse.php">Deployed Mouse</option>
  <option value="viewkeyboard.php">Deployed Keyboards</option>
  <option value="viewmonitor.php">Deployed Monitors</option>
  <option value="viewlaptop.php">Deployed Laptops</option>
 </select>

</div><br clear="all">

<span style="padding-right: 10px; font-family: Questrial;"><a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</font></a></span>
<span style="font-family: Questrial;"><a href="home.php" class="btn btn-primary">Profile</font></a></span>
```

The gap between the top border and the `select` is caused by the font size. To remove the gap, reduce the `font-size` or set a smaller `line-height`.

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  font-family: Questrial;
  /* font-size: 20px; */
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  /* padding: 100px; */
}
```

```html
<div style="font-family: Questrial; font-size:40px;">Administrative Control Panel Page</div><br>

<div id="container">

  <select id="MySelectCPU" onchange="location = this.value;">
  <option disabled selected hidden>Deployed Equipments</option>
  <option value="viewcpu.php">Deployed CPUs</option>
  <option value="viewmouse.php">Deployed Mouse</option>
  <option value="viewkeyboard.php">Deployed Keyboards</option>
  <option value="viewmonitor.php">Deployed Monitors</option>
  <option value="viewlaptop.php">Deployed Laptops</option>
 </select>

</div><br clear="all">

<span style="padding-right: 10px; font-family: Questrial;"><a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</font></a></span>
<span style="font-family: Questrial;"><a href="home.php" class="btn btn-primary">Profile</font></a></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of height, width and padding, use positioning:

```html
<div style="font-family: Questrial; font-size:40px;">Administrative Control Panel Page</div><br>


 <div style="width:500px; font-family: Questrial; font-size:20px; border:1px solid #000; padding:100px;position:relative;" >
 
 <select id="MySelectCPU" onchange="location = this.value;" style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;">
  <option disabled selected hidden>Deployed Equipments</option>
  <option value="viewcpu.php">Deployed CPUs</option>
  <option value="viewmouse.php">Deployed Mouse</option>
  <option value="viewkeyboard.php">Deployed Keyboards</option>
  <option value="viewmonitor.php">Deployed Monitors</option>
  <option value="viewlaptop.php">Deployed Laptops</option>
 </select>

 </div><br clear="all">
 
 <span style="padding-right: 10px; font-family: Questrial;" ><a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</font></a></span>
 <span style="font-family: Questrial;"><a href="home.php" class="btn btn-primary">Profile</font></a></span>
```

The above snippet has some changes. I positioned the parent div relative, and the select element absolute, with 10px distance from top en left border of the parent div.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to set the parent `div`'s positioning to `relative`, then you can use `absolute` positioning on the `select` element with the `top` set to `0` and `left` to `0`.

Edit: this would be useful if the `align` and `padding` were properties you want to keep, but override with this element.

Answer (score 2):

You have `.` in CSS it looks for a class.
`.MySelectCPU { ...`

But you have declared it as a ID element in HTML, should be `class=MySelectCPU` and not `id=` or change it to `#MySelectCPU` in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You have `align="center"` on the parent div. Remove it to align the Select box on left and then adjust padding accordingly to get it at the position you want.

```html
<div style="font-family: Questrial; font-size:40px;">Administrative Control Panel Page</div><br>


 <div style="width:500px; font-family: Questrial; font-size:20px; border:1px solid #000; padding:10px 5px;">
 
 <select id="MySelectCPU" onchange="location = this.value;">
  <option disabled selected hidden>Deployed Equipments</option>
  <option value="viewcpu.php">Deployed CPUs</option>
  <option value="viewmouse.php">Deployed Mouse</option>
  <option value="viewkeyboard.php">Deployed Keyboards</option>
  <option value="viewmonitor.php">Deployed Monitors</option>
  <option value="viewlaptop.php">Deployed Laptops</option>
 </select>

 </div><br clear="all">
 
 <span style="padding-right: 10px; font-family: Questrial;" ><a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</font></a></span>
 <span style="font-family: Questrial;"><a href="home.php" class="btn btn-primary">Profile</font></a></span>
```